# Angularjs - Fetch object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 separate json objects coming from the server. Json A below is of a Car model object which is fetch when looking at a car. Json B is meta data which is used throughout the whole application when the web page first loads.

What I need to do is have a lookup on `wheel_id` while doing a ng-repeat on `wheel_handlers` so it returns the wheel object from json B and then I can use this within the view and print the results. I think I need to do something with the ng-repeat but I'm not sure to be honest.

A - Car model

```
[{
  id: 14,
  name: "Audi",
  wheel_handlers: [
  {
    id: 9,
    wheel_id: 62,
    arguments: {
      amount: 10
    }
  }
  ]
}]
```

B - wheel

```
{
  id: 62,
  name: "Change Wheel Size",
  arguments: [
  {
    id: 25,
    description: "amount"
  }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the following: The Json "A" may include several cars, but also several wheel_handlers (because there is an array at `wheel_handler`). So the JSON for the cars may also look like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 14,
        name: "Audi",
        wheel_handlers: [
            {
                id: 9,
                wheel_id: 62,
                arguments: {
                    amount: 10
                }
            },
            {
                id: 12,
                wheel_id: 65,
                arguments: {
                    amount: 12
                }
            },
            {
                id: 15,
                wheel_id: 30,
                arguments: {
                    amount: 8
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Mercedes",
        wheel_handlers: [
            {
                id: 9,
                wheel_id: 62,
                arguments: {
                    amount: 10
                }
            },
            {
                id: 12,
                wheel_id: 65,
                arguments: {
                    amount: 12
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For the JSON file B I assume that you also meant an Array, which could contain several wheel definitions. As an example:

```
[
    {
        id: 62,
        name: "Change Wheel Size",
        arguments: [
            {
                id: 25,
                description: "amount"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 65,
        name: "test wheel",
        arguments: [
            {
                id: 25,
                description: "amount"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 30,
        name: "another wheel",
        arguments: [
            {
                id: 25,
                description: "amount"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If this is the case, you could iterate over the cars and while iterating call a helper function in the AngularJS controller. You call this helper function and give `wheel_handlers` of the current car as a parameter. This helper function then checks the `wheel_id` of each `wheel_handler` entry and searches these ids in the JSON b file - the wheel definitions. The helper function returns an array containing the wheels, so in the view you may iterate over the wheels. This will use a nested `ng-repeat`, because at first you iterate over the cars and while iterating over the cars you will iterate over the wheels.

Here is an example of the controller part. I used `$scope.cars` as the JSON A, and `$scope.wheels` as JSON B.

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testContr', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cars = [];
    $scope.wheels = [];

    $scope.getWheelsByIds = function (wheel_handlers) {
        var wheelIds = [];
        var returnArray = [];

        for (var wheelKey in wheel_handlers) {
            wheelIds.push(wheel_handlers[wheelKey].wheel_id);
        }

        for (var key in $scope.wheels) {
            console.log(wheelIds.indexOf($scope.wheels[key].id));
            if (wheelIds.indexOf($scope.wheels[key].id) > -1) {
                returnArray.push($scope.wheels[key]);
            }
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
});
```

The necessary HTML part could look like this:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testContr">
    <div ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-init="wheels = getWheelsByIds(car.wheel_handlers)">
        <span>Car name: {{car.name}}</span><br/>
        <div ng-repeat="wheel in wheels">
            <span>Wheel name: {{wheel.name}}</span><br/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I create a fiddle demonstration with the test data, view it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4F3YD/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of angular filter over here. In the filter function you can check for the id in the second json.

More [Documentation on Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Code Example:

```
 <div ng-repeat="element in wheel | filterIds:element.id">
```

And filter Function:

```
.filter('filterIds', function () {
    return function(id) {
       $scope.carModel.forEach(function(car){
             if(id == car.id)
                 return id;
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest ng-repeats like that, although I'm not sure what you want to achieve

following code will repeat through cars, then wheels in cars and display wheels from object B(wheels) that match the car wheel id, hope that makes sense

```
<div ng-repeat="car in CarModels">
  <div ng-repeat="wheel in car.wheel_handlers">
    {{Wheels | filter:wheel.wheel_id}}
  </div>
</div>
```